# Google Search Console errors occuring and disappearing all the time

Tags: google-search-console, mobile, responsive-webdesign, usability

In the Google Search Console I keep getting some errors under "Mobile Usability" that pop up every once in a while and then disappear again. To be more exact, it's these two errors mainly, that come and go periodically. I get them every two or three weeks:

- Text too small to read
- Clickable elements too close together

I looked at the involved pages that have this error and couldn't identify any of the named problems. What could be causing this? Do I have to be concerned at all?

Edit: Here is the screenshot that has been asked for.
[image]

Two pages that recently have been affected by the second error are these two:

- https://www.intes-akademie.de/seminare/referenten/andreas-meyer/
- https://www.intes-akademie.de/seminare/referenten/prof-dr-jack-nasher/

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot? That would be very helpful. A screenshot of these errors and probably a link of a URL page affected. By the way, you can do a check with Lighthouse (on Google Chrome) to fix some usability issues; that was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly common, however, the frequency that you are experiencing it is not.

I manage SEO for a lot of websites, and only see this come up every once in a while. I hit "validate fix" and in a few days it's gone.

As far as indexability/crawlability goes, you **don't** have to be concerned.

However, you **do** need to be concerned about site performance.

Googlebot's rendering can be inconsistent based on how efficiently a site loads its pages. This error is often indicative of greater site speed issues.

Please run a test on [Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/)

If everything looks OK, then you don't need to be concerned with this. It is likely just Googlebot/Search Console being buggy.

Feel free to drop me a link to the test results, and I can look at this if you like.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help. Here are two results of two affected pages. It seems okish to me:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.intes-akademie.de%2Fseminare%2Freferenten%2Fprof-dr-jack-nasher%2F
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.intes-akademie.de%2Fseminare%2Freferenten%2Fandreas-meyer%2F

Comment: @TheKidsWantDjent From what I saw I would say it is likely that performance is causing it. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it :)